# Touchscreen-type scrolling using mouse or pen

Tags: mouse, touchscreen, xinput, graphics-tablet, stylus

I'm looking for a system-level function to use the mouse pointer as a touch source for scrolling, when a certain key or (preferably) mouse/pen button is pressed.

For example, it would allow me to use my pen position for fine-tuned scrolling while I'm holding a pen button. I don't want to lose any existing functionality.

I have tried using [Scrollbar Anywhere for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrollbar-anywhere/namcaplenodjnggbfkbopdbfngponici) for a while, and it makes my life a lot easier. However, this has some major drawbacks:

- Only works in Chrome browser, not in the rest of your OS;
- Doesn't use pointer touch but scrollbar lock, effectively scrolling the exact opposite from intuitive;
- Right-click-hold to activate scroll prevents right-click-release menu.

Scrolling with a nudge of your pen (or mouse) is so convenient, I believe something like this can't not exist. I just don't know where to look. Could someone tell me where to look?